# Expected value of a bridge hand

Tags: probability

I'm trying to find the expected value of a 13 card bridge hand. Here's the problem:

In the point system used in the card game Bridge, ranks 2 through 10 are worth 0 points, a jack is worth 1 point, a queen 2 points, a king 3 points, and an ace 4 points. (Bridge is played with a standard 52 card deck.) What is the expected value for the point total of a 13 card hand?

I tried to write out each possible point total (I think it would be anything between 0 and 37), but the probabilities are fairly complicated and I'm not seeing a pattern where I could use a series to compute the expected value. I'm wondering if I need to do the combinatorics for each of the 37 values and then add them all up, or is there a better way?

Comment: The average is $10$, which is $1/4$th the total points in the deck. It's harder when you want to deal with distribution, but the raw high card points are essentially trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that we are skipping over the commonly used pointvalues for suits which you have two or fewer cards (which will make the problem a great deal harder):

Notice that the total point values of all four players' hands will be $4\cdot 4 + 3\cdot 4 + 2\cdot 4 + 1 \cdot 4 = 16 + 12 + 8 + 4 = 40$.  Given that points are randomly distributed among the players, it should be that the expected total points of a hand is $\frac{40}{4} = 10$.